# Downgrade Mongo version 3.6 to 2.x

Tags: mongodb

i have upgraded Ubuntu OS to 18.04, this cause my mongo db version upgrade from 2.4 to 3.6. 
i have tried to downgrade but i think there is compatibility issue with OS 18.04

Comment: Why do you need to downgrade? Any showstopper in 3.6 ?

Comment: There's literally no question in this post? Why did you post this? What do you want us to help you with?

Comment: i am using mongo 2.4 version on production branch, and i am not able to work locally because of mongo 3.6 version. is there a way to downgrade mongo version?

Comment: Since 2.4 is actually way past end of life for official support, then I would suggest the real issue here is that you should not be using it in production. Instructions for [installing specific versions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-the-mongodb-packages) has always been included in the official documentation. As is general instruction on "pinning" a specific version so that package upgrades don't happen, but the wider topic is more "system specific" than MongoDB specific.